# memcpy to copy array with offset

Tags: swift, memcpy

I have a huge array that I want to copy only a middle portion of it. I'm trying to use `memcpy` for the performance, but can't figure out a way to do so. Below is an example. How do we provide an offset to the source?

```swift
var source: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var dest: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

memcpy(&dest[2], source, 5)

print(dest) // [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0]
// This works
```

```swift
var source: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var dest: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

memcpy(&dest[2], &source[2], 5)

print(dest) // [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
// Only `source[2]` is copied
```

Comment: "I'm trying to use memcpy for the performance." Performance vs what?

Comment: My assumption is that this is the fastest method available, low-level raw memory copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceSubrange()` for that purpose:

```swift
let source: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
var dest: [UInt8] =   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

dest.replaceSubrange(2..<(2+5), with: source[2..<(2+5)])
print(dest) // [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

or simply assign a source slice to a destination slice:

```swift
dest[2..<(2+5)] = source[2..<(2+5)]
print(dest) // [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

#### Benchmark

on a MacBook Air M2, with the code compiled in Release configuration.

```
import Foundation

let N = 1_000_000 // Length of source and destination array
let sourceStart = 500
let destinationStart = 2000
let length = 12345

let source: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 5, count: N)

for _ in 1...10 {
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest[destinationStart..<(destinationStart+length)].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { p in
            source.copyBytes(to: p, from: sourceStart..<sourceStart + length)
        }
        let end = Date()
        print("copyBytes:      ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        source.withUnsafeBytes { sourcePtr in
            _ = memcpy(&dest[destinationStart], sourcePtr.baseAddress! + sourceStart, length)
        }
        let end = Date()
        print("memcpy:         ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest.replaceSubrange(destinationStart..<(destinationStart+length),
                             with: source[sourceStart..<(sourceStart+length)])
        
        let end = Date()
        print("replaceSubrange:", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest[destinationStart..<(destinationStart+length)]
            = source[sourceStart..<(sourceStart+length)]
        
        let end = Date()
        print("slicing:        ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    print()
}
```

Results:

```
copyBytes:       0.010013580322265625 ms
memcpy:          0.0010728836059570312 ms
replaceSubrange: 0.009059906005859375 ms
slicing:         0.010013580322265625 ms
```

Comment: interesting, I always thought `memcpy` is a low-level method that is the fastest by simply copying the memory. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SonNguyen I thought that too. But the difference here isn't actually that big when you are copying *really* large ranges that are similar to the size of the array itself. The latter two seems to be about 30% faster at best.

Comment: @SonNguyen I found where the problem is. Apparently taking an open-ended slice is where the bottleneck it. It apparently copies the array if you call `withUnsafeBytes` on it. I've edited my answer to make it a little better, though still not better than `replaceSubrange` and slicing.

Comment: @Martin R, found the issue with your memcpy. We only need 1 withUnsafeBytes on the source, `memcpy(&dest[destinationStart], sourcePtr.baseAddress, length)`. With this change, memcpy is the most superior one

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the Swift pointer APIs instead.

When dealing with `UInt8` arrays, you can use [`copyBytes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dataprotocol/3139166-copybytes). Take a slice of the destination array, get a buffer pointer from that, and copy a range of the source to that buffer.

```
let destinationStart = 2
let sourceStart = 2
let sourceEnd = 7
let length = sourceEnd - sourceStart
let destinationEnd = destinationStart + length
dest[destinationStart..<destinationEnd].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { p in
    source.copyBytes(to: p, from: sourceStart..<sourceEnd)
}
```

If you want to use `memcpy`, you can get the buffer pointer from the source, and add the source offset to it.

```
source.withUnsafeBytes { sourcePtr in
    memcpy(&dest[destinationStart], sourcePtr.baseAddress! + sourceStart, length)
}
```

Comment: A minor remark: `withUnsafeBytes` (without “mutable”) suffices for the source and allows that to be declared as a constant.

Comment: It should and it has: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/memcpy.3.html :) – It would be interesting to test if this low-level is faster than replaceSubrange or a slice assignment. Perhaps I'll do some performance testing when I find the time.

Comment: I have added my benchmark results. I would have guessed that the “low-level” methods are faster, but that is not the case. I cannot explain why. You are welcome to verify those results, perhaps I made some error in how it was measured.

Comment: I wonder if copyBytes/memcpy make some (unwanted) copy. Even with length = 0 or 1 these methods take a non-trivial  amount of time for large arrays.

Comment: @Sweeper @Martin R, we actually need only 1 `withUnsafeBytes`, and that shows the true speed of `memcpy`. Please see my answer based on Martin's one

Comment: @MartinR I managed to get a version of `memcpy` that is a lot faster than slicing. Apparently using pointer arithmetic instead of slicing the array first makes a difference. The updated version is like an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: @Sweeper: Indeed, copyBytes/replaceSubrange/slicing are now all equally fast, and memcpy is considerably faster (as one would expect). I have updated my benchmarking report. – However, I am not sure if it is *guaranteed* that `&dest[destinationStart]` returns a pointer into the original element storage.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be working:

```
import Foundation

var source: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var dest: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

memcpy(&dest[2], UnsafePointer<UInt8>(&source) + 2, 5)

print(dest) // [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

and gives bunch of warnings:

Initialization of 'UnsafePointer' results in a dangling pointer

Implicit argument conversion from '[UInt8]' to 'UnsafePointer' produces a pointer valid only for the duration of the call to 'init(_:)'

Use the 'withUnsafeBufferPointer' method on Array in order to explicitly convert argument to buffer pointer valid for a defined scope

withUnsafePointer gets rid of warnings:

```
import Foundation

var source: [UInt8] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var dest: [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

let _ = withUnsafePointer(to: &source[2])
{ 
    memcpy(&dest[2], $0, 5) 
}

print(dest) // [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
```

And there still going to be problem with different data types.
Stride in memory seems to be same regardless of data type.

Comment: The warnings are there for a reason. The code invokes undefined behavior and may fail at any time.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @Martin R, I have edited his benchmark code and `memcpy` is still way faster than slicing:

```
import Foundation
import UserModule

let N = 1_000_000 // Length of source and destination array
let sourceStart = 50
let destinationStart = 2000
let length = 12345

let source: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 5, count: N)

for _ in 1...10 {
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest[destinationStart...].withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { p in
            source.copyBytes(to: p, from: sourceStart..<sourceStart + length)
        }
        let end = Date()
        print("copyBytes:      ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        source[sourceStart...].withUnsafeBytes { sourcePtr in
            _ = memcpy(&dest[destinationStart], sourcePtr.baseAddress, length)
        }
        
        let end = Date()
        print("memcpy:         ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest.replaceSubrange(destinationStart..<(destinationStart+length),
                             with: source[sourceStart..<(sourceStart+length)])
        
        let end = Date()
        print("replaceSubrange:", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    do {
        var dest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: N)
        let start = Date()
        
        dest[destinationStart..<(destinationStart+length)]
            = source[sourceStart..<(sourceStart+length)]
        
        let end = Date()
        print("slicing:        ", end.timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000, "ms")
    }
    print()
}
```

That has the benchmark result:

```
copyBytes:       63.13800811767578 ms
memcpy:          0.0680685043334961 ms
replaceSubrange: 334.49602127075195 ms
slicing:         5.218029022216797 ms
```

Comment: Running on Playground, M1 Pro macbook

Comment: Never do benchmarking in a Playground. Use a compiled project with “Release” configuration. (Not my downvote, I and don't claim that you are wrong. But this is not a conclusive test.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do it next time. But I also apply this to my app in debug mode, able to achieve a lot more fps with `memcpy`